# How can I have a javascript object that has a type of Java.util.Arraylist?

Tags: java, javascript

Tinkering around with the Solr ScriptUpdateProcessor, so I have a javascript file that is executing without a browser. I'm new enough at this that I don't know how to run this in a debugger, and am limited to system logging.

In this javascript file, I have an object that I thought was an array, but was oddly missing the basic properties of javascript arrays.

So I used dumped the object using this function:

```
function log_object(object) {
  var output = '';
    for (var property in object) {
       output += property + ': ' + object[property]+'; \n';
   }
   logger.info(output);
}
```

And the result that came back looks like "real" Java. Most notably:

```
class: class java.util.ArrayList;
```

More of this was:

```
clone: function clone() {/*
java.lang.Object clone()
*/}
;
toArray: function toArray() {/*
java.lang.Object[] toArray()
java.lang.Object[] toArray(java.lang.Object[])
*/}
;
iterator: function iterator() {/*
java.util.Iterator iterator() 
*/}
;
addAll: function addAll() {/*
boolean addAll(int,java.util.Collection)
boolean addAll(java.util.Collection)
*/}
;
get: function get() {/*
java.lang.Object get(int) 
*/}
;
equals: function equals() {/*
boolean equals(java.lang.Object)
*/}
```

etc.
Mind blown.

How did I end up with a basic java object inside a javascript function?  What is going on here?

## Update

There is some grey area of java-to-and-from-javascript that I wasn't previously aware of.
The final "working code" in test-update-script.js looks like this:

```
doc = cmd.solrDoc;  // org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument <- note this is also java?
var contents = []; <-- 'normal' js Array.
vals = doc.getFieldValues(my_multivalued_field); // <--- vals is now java.util.arraylist
jsFriendlyAry = vals.toArray(); // <-- jsFriendlyAry is String[]
for (j = 0; j < jsFriendlyAry.length; j++) {
    contents.push(jsFriendlyAry[j]);
}
```

So it is possible to mix server-side javascript and java. The snippets in [Oracle's guide to using Java from Scripts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html#A1147227)
seem to need an include I haven't figured out yet (particularly Java.to and Java.from), but confirm the behavior.

Comment: Never heard of `ScriptingUpdateRequestHandler`, and Google didn't either. Can you provide a link? Nevertheless, the only way it would happen is - someone defined the class you're using and made it look like the Java's.

Comment: That seems unlikely.  Got the name of the utility wrong - correcting the OP. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ScriptUpdateProcessor

Comment: This appears to be compiling from javascript into actual java.

Comment: May I suggest a change in the title of your question ? As it is it suggests that you are actually trying to use an ArrayList in JavaScript, which does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update scripts are by default executed using Java's support for scripting (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_7_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory.html)

In the original implementation of [Rhino Javascript engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29) that JS was compiled into Java classes, and that the scripts have been interpreted since 1998.

So it still seems like those scripts are run as Java, from Java, rather than in isolation. Which explains why the dumped objects had more in common with POJOs than 'normal' JS objects.